# Passing data to imported component on v-for

Tags: wordpress, vuejs2

I'm struggling with this for a while now. I am doing a v-for using a custom component called Post to loop through an array of wordpress posts. It's worth noting that the loop works if I place a regular HTML element instead (notice the `<li>` element below). This is how my Hello.vue looks:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <section class="posts__Feed">
      <ul class="posts__List">
        <post v-for="item in posts" v-bind="item" :item="item" :key="item.id"></post>

        <li v-for="item in posts">{{ item.id }}</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
var postsUrl = '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/'
import Post from '@/components/Post.vue'

export default {
  name: 'hello',
  components: {
    Post
  },
  data () {
    return {
      posts: []
    }
  },
  beforeCreate () {
    this.$http.get(postsUrl).then((response) => {
      this.posts = response.data
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

And this is my Post.vue file:

```
<template>
  <li>
    <p class="posts__ItemAuthor">{{ item.id }}</p>
  </li>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'post',
  data () {
    return {
      item: []
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v-bind` should be combined with the property you are binding to

```
<post v-for="item in posts" v-bind:item="item" :key="item.id"></post>
```

And your component should accept `item` as a property.

```
export default {
  props:["item"],
  name: 'post'
}
```

Comment: That's it! Wow, I was really close. I did try that but I guess I was too tired of trying out a bunch of other stuff so I must have missed something. Thanks!

Comment: @twenty no problem ;)